# Add a status LED to an existing device

Tags: led, transistors, switching

I'm currently converting an old MP3-player (a Creative Zen Stone) to a standalone music player for my children. One of the things I'd like to do is to add an LED which shows whether the device is powered on or off.

Due to how the MP3-player is built, the only place where I can easily modify the circuit is between the battery and the device itself. Therefore, my idea was to place the LED in parallel to the device and use a transistor to switch it on whenever there's a current flowing through the player.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fzXS7q.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The battery says that it delivers 3.7V. The green LED needs 20mA at a forward voltage of 2.1V, so given the 3.7V from the battery it needs an 80Ω resistor. I'm currently using a 100Ω one, because that's the closest that I got.

This design somewhat works, in the sense that when I power on the MP3-player the LED lights up. However, it seems the player doesn't get enough voltage now, because it doesn't work properly (which it does without the additional elements attached). The base-emitter saturation voltage of my transistor is around 0.7V (accordingly, I'm measuring that the player only gets 3.0V).

How can I resolve this problem? Is there a different circuit design that I can use or should I start looking for a transistor with a very low base-emitter saturation voltage instead (assuming those exist)?

Comment: That's an interesting approach. I've redrawn your schematic in the conventional manner with positive on top and negative on the bottom. You have the battery polarity reversed on your diagram.

Comment: @Transistor Thanks! I'm farely new to electronics, so I haven't picked up all the conventions, yet.

Comment: If it's a "standalone music player", perhaps you should replace the battery with a wall-wart power supply.

Comment: Ain't there an led that shows it's on?

Comment: @Reinderien I want to keep the design "wireless" with regard to power supply. Using another battery might be an option, however, I'm afraid that this might interfere with the charging logic of the MP3-player.

Comment: @JasonHan There is. However, I'd like to enclose the player in a bigger case that's easier to handle for children. Exposing the existing LED in that case would be very challenging due to the geometry of the player. In addition, the existing LED is soldered very tightly in the middle of the player's circuit and I don't think I could attach or remove any elements there.

Comment: Since there is already a LED there, you could run a polymer light pipe to the surface of the new case.

Comment: @Reinderien that actually sounds pretty nice, but I never tried to build a light pipe myself. But the idea of using the original led has something: Florian could use a phototransistor to "read" the LED!

Comment: The phototransistor would be clever and hilarious, but since this is a battery-operated unit, I would hesitate to add any circuitry unless really required. You don't have to build your own light pipe: you can buy them stock - https://www.digikey.ca/products/en/optoelectronics/optics-light-pipes/102

Comment: @Reinderien Interesting idea! Do you have any pointers on where to learn more about using polymer light pipes?

Comment: http://www.electronicdesign.com/components/fundamentals-led-light-pipes , https://www.fictiv.com/hwg/design/learn-by-example-how-to-design-light-pipes , for example

Answer (score 7):

Have a look at the [LM124 comparator](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm2902.pdf).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fwLa6y.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. The LM124 can compare inputs down to 0 V. They feature an open-collector output suitable for driving the LED.*

How it works:

- The comparator, as the name suggests, switches its output based on the comparison of its inputs. If IN+ > IN- output switches high. If IN+ < IN- output switches low.
- We'll assume that you can tolerate a 0.1 V drop on your power supply and that your MP3 device draws > 50 mA when on.
- We need to set R1 to a value that will generate > 0.1 V at 50 mA. \$ R1 = \frac {V}{I} = \frac {0.1}{0.05} = 2 \; \Omega \$. 2.2 Ω is the nearest standard value above 2 and will generate a slightly higher voltage which will make the system more reliable.
- R2 and R3 create a voltage divider to hold IN+ at about 0.1 V.
- C1 holds this voltage steady in case voltage fluctuates with volume of the player.
- When the device is turned on IN- voltage will be greater than IN+, the output will switch low and D1 will light.

Measure the current drawn by your device in standby and recalculate for R1.

The LM124 is available in 8-pin 0.1" DIL chip which you will be able to solder or insert in a DIL socket.

Welcome to the world of electronics. This is an interesting little project. If you take my approach you'll read through the datasheet, learn how to pronounce the words, study the graphs, wonder what it all means but start to figure it out from context and studying other circuits and application notes.

Comment: You'll also learn how to spell "comparator" :)

Comment: Nice. Another note: R2 and R3 have (probably intentionally) been designed "strong", i.e.  the ca. 100 µA that flow through these at all times have been chosen so that they are in the same order of magnitude as the Opamp/comparators supply current, and sufficiently larger than the input leakage currents. If you can find an Opamp that uses less quiescent current than the LM124 (that is certainly possible, but finding one that can compare voltages ~ 0.1V over negative supply isn't easy), then increasing the values of R2 and R3 (and decreasing C1) would result in longer battery life.

Comment: And: it's very possible that under full load (i.e. high volume into low-impedance earpieces), the MP3 player might draw much more than 50 mA, so that it'll sense weak battery when things get loud. In that case, you'd need to reduce R1 – but that would conflict with reliable detection; not sure how Transistor would solve that problem :)

Comment: Idea: maybe replace R1 with a Schottky diode, which has a nonlinear Voltage-over-current curve? Schottkys with Vf of 0.1 to 0.2V at ~50 mA do [exist](http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/427/vs-10bq015hm3-1074219.pdf) and aren't that expensive. That way, you'd never get a "large" voltage drop

Comment: @Reinderien: Thanks. I've fixed my spill chick. Everytink is spelt properley know.

Comment: @MarcusMüller: All good points. I kept the resistors high for battery life. The bias currents could be an issue. The Schottky diode might do the trick too.

Comment: @Transistor I looked into TI's LM124/LM2909 data sheet and it specifies nanoamperes of input bias current, but potentially ~ 1mA of supply current in a no-load situation, so that's why I worried more about the opamp supply current than the input bias currents.

Comment: The [TLV8801](http://www.ti.com/product/tlv8801) looks like a nice alternative :) (especially since it's so bandwidth-limited – no need for noise reduction, i.e. C1 might be some 10 nF or omitted completely) (NB: will need to add mosfet or BJT to drive LED from opamp output)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed breakdown, this is very much appreciated! My battery says it provides 140 mAh, so that 100 µA "leakage" should be acceptable. However, I don't understand why such a leakage is necessary from a theoretical point of view: why do I need to spend energy when I'm not doing anything like switching or powering the player and the LED?

Comment: Because you have a powered monitoring circuit.

Answer (score 1):

For power indication a good super-bright 5000mcd (cheap)  Red LED only needs 2mA or ~ 760 Ohms across MP3 player input DC to get 500mcd offered in poor LEDs at 20mA

Then keep switch to MP3 wired as before.  This way there is no voltage drop and minimal current load. Get the right LED and R.

https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/wurth-electronics-inc/151054RS03000/732-11408-ND/7315780. $0.23 (1)

You dont need a transistor when you have a mechanical switch to do the job.

nowgeterdun

### added

**The best LED feature is the one built in** which is better and could be brighter by careful selection in a larger 5mm case without drawing more current and more useful than anything else suggested.

[image]
My measuring the voltage on each pin, one can determine which is common cathode to ground or common anode to V+.

You can replace it with a 2 colour R/G 5mm case mounted LED readily available from Mouser/Digikey etc and use AWG30 magnet wire used in many wallworts for the primary winding if you dont have any surplus.

When both R + G are active it may appear yellow to orange.
such [**as**](https://www.digikey.com/products/en/optoelectronics/led-indication-discrete/105?k=red%20green&k=&pkeyword=red%20green&FV=94007b%2C9402f8%2Cffe00069&mnonly=0&ColumnSort=-206&page=1&stock=1&quantity=0&ptm=0&fid=0&pageSize=250) <<

Comment: Thanks for your input! However, I'm not sure I understand: in my current design, the LED is not the problem, the voltage drop between base and emitter is. And the LED you mention has a forward voltage of 1.9 V, so putting it in series with the player will get even less voltage to the player than my current design. In addition, the player is switched on by holding the "play / pause" button for several seconds, so I can't simply hook into that without duplicating some logic (that's why I'm trying to get at it via the battery).

Comment: Don't change anything in your MP3 player power connections ok?  No drop  voltage, no transistor ,nothing in series. Just share voltage in parallel with LED which uses a series R as I said above.

Comment: That won't work: if I add the LED in parallel to the player then it will be always on, since it's directly attached to the battery. I need to take into account whether a current is flowing through the player. The options I know of are to put the LED in series with the player (not enough voltage), use a transistor as in my original post (not enough voltage) or use an comparator as @Transistor has suggested. If you can think of another option then I'd be grateful for a more detailed explanation, since I seem to be missing your point.

Comment: doh .. last time I explain this. it goes across mp3 after the switch, not across the battery so it is only On when switch is On.

Comment: Sorry, but I still don't understand. As I mentioned before, there is no mechanical switch, so I'm not sure what you mean by "across mp3 after the switch".

Comment: I meant the internal power switch, but after reading the manual it already has an LED battery monitor, so why bother?

Comment: See [my previous comment](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/323648/add-a-status-led-to-an-existing-device/323665?noredirect=1#comment755620_323648): "[...] I'd like to enclose the player in a bigger case that's easier to handle for children. Exposing the existing LED in that case would be very challenging due to the geometry of the player. In addition, the existing LED is soldered very tightly in the middle of the player's circuit and I don't think I could attach or remove any elements there."

Comment: Requirements in a design ought to be included in question not comments.  AWG 30 magnet wire can be soldered to pads to bring out the LED to the surface . It can be replaced with a 5mm Red/Yellow LED  The function of this LED is far superior to anything else suggested. Since it detects low voltage before/after failure then changes indications.

Comment: Are you planning to expose the buttons or hardwire other switches?